# Display Unicode characters in Struts textfield

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, struts2

I have a struts textfield `<s:textfield/>` where I need to display unicode characters as placeholder text. This placeholder text is retrieved from a DB2 database where it is stored in HTML codes like `&#xxxx;`. But when I do the following:
`<s:textfield placeholder="&#xxxx;"/>`
It shows up as is and the character is not displayed!

I already have tried all unicode headers (`@page content-type, <meta charset>, etc`) in the file and the file is encoded in UTF-8.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have this line <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> in your head tag?

Comment: Yes, I have this line, as well as I have tried the `@page` alternative, and `<meta charset="utf-8">` as well

Comment: delete your @page content-type line and just have my statement in your head tag

Comment: How do you put `placeholder` value from db?